# RecyclerView or ListView vertical with row layout with wrap_content

Tags: java, android, xml, listview, android-recyclerview

I want show a list of `TextView`s in a vertical `RecycleView` or `ListView` and It's easy but the `TextView` use the whole width, I want when the `TextView` ends before use the whole width, the next item of the `ListView` begins in the leftover width. example:

item1 textview blablalbablalba
blalblabla.  **item2 textviewvav**
**blablablalblabllabllalb.** item3
fsafsfsfsfsfsffsfs.

How can I do that???

Should I do a custom TextView or a custom RecyclerView/ListView or what??

I have de row.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:orientation="vertical">

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/row_scripture_textView"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:textSize="10sp" />

 </LinearLayout>
```

And the RecyclerView

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/rv_scripture"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

java

```java
RecyclerView rvScripture = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.rv_scripture);
rvScripture.setAdapter(new ScriptureAdapter(getActivity(), myArrayObjs));
rvScripture.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
```

And this is my Adapter.

```java
public class ScriptureAdapter extends 
RecyclerView.Adapter<ScriptureAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<String> data = Collections.emptyList();

    public ScriptureAdapter(Context context, List<String> data) {
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_scripture, parent, false);
        MyViewHolder viewHolder = new MyViewHolder(view);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        String current = data.get(position);
        holder.textView.setText(current);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView textView;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            textView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.row_scripture_textView);
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: What are you planning on using this list for? Does it have more functionality or is it just for show?

Comment: @MohamedYassin just for show, I want the option to view one item below another (normal behavior) and as I explained in the cuestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is achievable by using Spannable class in one huge TextView.

```
SpannableStringBuilder builder = new SpannableStringBuilder();
```

and put all loaded data into a list of string, then as iterating them,

you append previous data to the next one until you reach the end of data.

Let me know how it goes!

Comment: Dude I don't know how to thank you! I love you! I didn't know about Spannable and that stuff, I was researching about Spans and I solved future problems. Actually you don't solve my question but you guided me :)

Answer (score 0):

If the data is just for show, then I would recommend the easiest solution would be to combine the data into a variable and output it into a TextView within a scrollview.

Comment: I thought that but and this is why Im using a RecyclerView/ListView..I need to click the items...I mean, each item is clickeable